# Can't connect node to SQL Server

Tags: node.js, sql-server, connection-string

I'm trying to connect a node app with a SQL Server database, but I keep getting this error:

> Error while connecting database: ConnectionError:
>
> Error: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]SQL Server Network Interfaces: Connection string is not valid [87].
> Error: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Login timeout expired
> Error: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.

I use the node package `mssql` with driver `msnodesqlv8`, and this is my db config:

```
const dbConfig = {
  user: "user",
  password: "password",
  driver: 'msnodesqlv8',
  server: 'DESKTOP-QG3R51Q',
  database: 'WeighingScales',
  options: {
    instanceName: 'SQLEXPRESS',
    trustedConnection: true,
  }
};
```

Comment: `DESKTOP-QG3R51Q` doesn't look like a proper server hostname. (this may work with NetBIOS but most likely not with DNS.) is this your local machine? If yes, use `localhost` instead.

Comment: Yes, it's my local machine, and that is the name of the server in mssql. I tried with localhost and nothing changed

Comment: Oh, right, I missed that it's MSSQL and not MySQL. Things may work differently there. Did you verify the things the error message asked you to, i.e. that instance name is correct and SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections?